Doubt in proof of differentiability of $\begin{equation} f(x,y)= \begin{cases} \frac{x^2y^2}{x^2+y^4}, \neq (0,0)\\ 0 \end{cases}\, \end{equation}$
Let $f$ be:
\begin{equation}
f(x,y)=
    \begin{cases}
       \frac{x^2y^2}{x^2+y^4}, (x,y) \neq (0,0) \\
      0, (x,y)=(0,0)
    \end{cases}\,
\end{equation}
Supposedly this is differentiable in (0,0).
But I think if we do the restriction of $f$ to the set $\{(x, \sqrt{x}) : x >0\}$, then the limit of $|\frac{f(x,y)-f(0,0)-0}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}|$ = $\frac{|f(x,y)|}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}$ as $(x,y)$ goes to $(0,0)$ becomes in module:
$$ \frac{|x|^3}{\sqrt{x^2+x} (2x^2)} =$$
$$ \frac{1}{\sqrt{|x|+1} (2)} =$$
Which goes to $\frac{1}{2}$...
What am I doing wrong? Thank you in advance.

But I've seen that if you use the inequalities $x^2 \leq x^2 + y^4 $ and $|y| \leq \sqrt{x^2+y^2}$, then it works...

Applying Gâteaux' derivative definiton, the derivative of $f$ at $\boldsymbol x_0=\mathbf 0$ in some direction $\boldsymbol{\hat u}$ is
$$\boldsymbol{\hat u}\cdot\boldsymbol\nabla f|_{\boldsymbol x_0=\mathbf 0}=\lim_{h\to 0}\dfrac{f(\mathbf 0+h\boldsymbol{\hat u})-f(\mathbf 0)}{h}=\lim_{h\to 0}\dfrac{h^4u_x^2u_y^2}{h(h^2u_x+h^4u_y)}=0$$
To verify the that we may apply the definiton of differentiability at that point, namely, checking that
$$\lim_{\boldsymbol x\to \mathbf 0}\dfrac{f(\mathbf 0+\boldsymbol x)-f(\mathbf 0)-\boldsymbol{x}\cdot\boldsymbol\nabla f|_{\boldsymbol x_0=\mathbf 0}}{||\boldsymbol x||}\overset{\text{polar coords.}}{=}\lim_{r\to 0}\dfrac{r\cos^2\theta\sin^2\theta}{\cos^2\theta+r^2\sin^4\theta}\overset{!}{=}0$$
which yields $0$ $\forall\theta$. Therefore, for the direction you suggested $y=\sqrt x$ it should hold too. Let's check it out:
$$\begin{aligned}
\lim_{\boldsymbol x\to \mathbf 0}\dfrac{f(\mathbf 0+\boldsymbol x)-f(\mathbf 0)-\boldsymbol{x}\cdot\boldsymbol\nabla f|_{\boldsymbol x_0=\mathbf 0}}{||\boldsymbol x||}&=\lim_{\boldsymbol x\to \mathbf 0}\dfrac{x^2y^2}{(x^2+y^4)\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}\\
&\hspace{-0.25cm}\overset{y=\sqrt x}{=}\lim_{x\to 0}\dfrac{x^3}{2x^2\sqrt{x^2+x}}\\
&=\lim_{x\to 0}\dfrac{\sqrt x}{2\sqrt{x+1}}\to 0
\end{aligned}$$
as we wanted.

Note that
$$f(x,\sqrt x)=\frac{x^2\sqrt x^4}{x^2+\sqrt x^4}=\frac{x^2\times x^2}{x^2+x^2}=\frac{x^4}{2x^2}$$
You put in
$$f(x,\sqrt x)=\frac{x^3}{2x^2}$$

Ohh you're absolutely right, I mispled the funcion. I'll edit it now, it is not $y^4$, but $y^2$!

Now it is right :)

Well as it turns out, I was making my calculations wrongly, in the direction $(x, \sqrt{x})$, we get
$$ \frac{\sqrt{x}}{\sqrt{x+1}×{2}} $$ which still goes to 0.
I'm sorry.
